# Communication among multiple instances of a program in peer to peer chat - C language

Tags: c, sockets, p2p

I'm writing a peer to peer chat program. In this program, client and server functionality are written in one unique file. First, I would like to ask whether the mechanism in my program is correct or not.

> 1. I fork() two processes, one for client functionality and one for server functionality
> 2. In server process, I initialize sockets, do bind(), listen(). Then I use select() to handle for multi-connections from clients. In client process, I initialize socket, do connect().
> 3. When the first peer is created, the client process doesn't have any server to connect with, so it just waits until other peers appear. In this case, I just initialize a socket and wait.
> 4. When next peers are created, their client processes initialize sockets, do connect() and send information to server process of the first peer to ask for joining.
> 5. In server process, I receive information after select() returns and send a feedback to the client process of sender.

Second, for example, my program is called "p2p". I start an instance(from my program) in one terminal, let say, P2P1 by running "**p2p Name_of_group  Port_Number_for_Server_Side**". This is the first peer of the network, it defines a name of a group, a port to listen. Now I run another instance (in another terminal), let say P2P2 by running "**p2p Name_of_group Port_Number_for_Server_Side**". This second peer states the name of a group it would like to join and a port to listen for its server process.

A client process of P2P2 connects to a server process of P2P1 by sending its information to the server process P2P1. However, in this case, the client process of P2P2 doesn't know the value of socket which is initialized to open a port in server process of P2P1. So my question is how to get this information from P2P1 when the P2P2 wants to communicate with P2P1 using send() and recv()? Thanks very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First question**: I would prefer to use one single process instead of two since data exchange would be simpler. Then choosing between a single thread solution (select()ing with no timeout from network and from user input in a loop) or a two threads solution I would probably stay for 2 threads, which is a little bit more complicated but more responsive to the user.

The rest of mechanism seems correct but may vary according to the implementation required by yor second question

**Second question**: I think that you always need to pass the hostname:port of at least one active client as argument.

I would develop this solution: if hostname:port are not passed then the client just does nothing (it's probably the first node of a network); if such info is present, then as first thing the client should try to connect to the given address.

The first contact should be followed by a special command that makes the contacted server to share info of every other active node in the network. In your case I would start P2P2 as "**p2p Name_of_group Port_Number_for_Server_Side Port_Number_of_P2P1**". Then

- P2P2 connects to P2P1 and ask for other nodes
- P2P1 answers that is is the only node
- now both P2P1 and P2P2 knows that the network is made of two nodes

Now you can start a P2P3 as "p2p Name_of_group Port_Number_for_Server_Side **Port_Number_of_P2P1**" or "p2p Name_of_group Port_Number_for_Server_Side **Port_Number_of_P2P2**". Let's assume you make it connect to P2P2

- P2P3 connects to P2P2 and asks for other active nodes
- P2P2 replies address info about P2P1
- P2P3 connects to P2P1 and do not ask for anything (or you can be redundant if you wish)

Comment: Hi Jack. Thanks very much for your comment and your suggested solutions, it quite makes sense to me. I decide to choose 1st solution using select() instead of 2 thread solution in the first question. However, I would like to clarify more your answer. My problem is how to keep the data of a first instance since I run a second instance(I mean data of first instance will be reset since I start the second instance). When I run the second instance, in while loop, it returns the sockets I would like to process, I don't know the value of socket of first instance's server side to check.

Comment: In while loop, I use select(), then I check condition by FD_ISSET(socket_descriptor_serverSide_1stInstance, &readData). But it doesn't jump into the condition since the socket_descriptor_serverSide_1stInstance is reset to initial value, not the value of the first instance.

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear to me what you meant. Can you clarify better your problem? In every instance you have to loop all over your socket descriptors (you will have 1 for server, and N for n-clients) and create the descriptor-set to be passed to select(); then FD_ISSET will let you know if one of this 1+N has something to say.

Comment: "I mean data of first instance will be reset since I start the second instance" this is not clear at all to me. Why should it be reset?

Comment: Hi Jack. For example, in first instance, at server side, I do initialize and get return by a socket_descriptor, let say S1 . Next, I want to connect client side(socket C2) of the second instance to server side of the first instance( by calling, let say, join() function). When the connection is successful, the condition FD_ISSET(S1, &readData) will happen in the first instance(not the second instance). My question is the readData set is not the same for both instances(readData includes S1 in the first instance, but it includes S2(socket of server side of 2nd instance, not S1)? Is this correct?

Comment: join() is a well used function name for joining thread.. I would avoid that name :)

Comment: You are running two instances, say APP1 and APP2. On APP1 you start your server A1#S1. On APP2 you create a socket A2#C1 connect it on A1#S1. A1#S1 get notified by select. On A1#S1 you call accept() and obtain A1#C1, which is the socket APP1 will use to talk to APP2. APP2 will still use A2#C1. Now when A1#C1 sends data, on APP2 your select(A2#C1) will get notified; When A2#C1 sends data, on APP1 your select(A1#C1) will get notified. 

Sorry it's hard to explain this in a comment, but it's quite simple.

Comment: I think you are missing the point that on a p2p connection one client connects to one server, but on server side, the server socket is only used to accept new connection; once a connection is accepted (by calling accept()) you get a new descriptor to communicate with such client

Comment: Hi Jack, I have one question from your comment about APP1 and APP2. On A1#S1, after calling accept() and obtain A1#C1, now I would like to send back information from A1#C1 to A2#C1(it happens right after the connection is successful, inside of the condition of A1#S1 get notified by select()). However, in this case, I don't know the socket of A2#C1, how can I specify the socket argument in send() function? Thanks again very much for your comment.

Comment: Sorry but I think you are missing basics. Why don't you take a look at some simple tutorial :). After you get the descriptor from accept() you can use it as first argument of send() to send data to A2. In A1's memory space you don't need to know anything else of A2 but its descriptor (yes.. it's an int)..

Comment: I got it. Thanks very much for your comment and sorry for dummy question.

Comment: Hi Jack,I would like to create a complete network among nodes(every node connects to the rest nodes). However, I have one problem as the following example. Let say, I have nodes A, B, C. First, A is initialized. Then B connects to A, then C connects to B and then B send new information of the network to both A and C. Now, every node can see 2 other nodes. Since I have to connect C with A, there is a problem in synchronization when both C and A would like to connect together after they receive information from B. How to handle this situation? Thanks very much for your comments.